# Spring web app database access outside managed beans

Tags: spring, web-applications, database-connection, managed-bean

In my web app i have an `applicationContext.xml` which i define beans database connection parameters etc. 
While i can make desired operations with managed beans (using services and daos) in a pojo class; i can not use those services and managed beans. Is there a way to access database from a pojo using parameters in application context? Every example i look using `@managedProperty` and managed beans. However it would be a bad design to define my pojo class as managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject the DataSource into the POJO (which is not normally managed by Spring) using the @Configurable annotation. See a way to do that [here](http://www.olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/)

Personally I would avoid going down the road of accessing the DB from a POJO if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using the existing data source bean.

Just auto wire the dataSource or use the applicationContext (helper class) to get the datasource and acquire a connection from it.
Then use prepared statement to do your native sql.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

  public void doBla(){
    // Open a database connection using Spring's DataSourceUtils
    Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource); // NOSONAR
    PreparedStatement countQuery = null;
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        countQuery = connection.prepareStatement("//put sql here");
        ResultSet countResult = countQuery.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //TODO do something here...
  }
 DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, dataSource);
}
```

Comment: this is not the best design i think however i am using 

`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../applicationContext.xml"); 
settingsMB = context.getBean(SettingsManagedBean.class);`
but the service in managedbean returns null.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved;
i tried

```
    private static ISettingsService settingsService;
    private static ApplicationContext context;
```

in constructor i called

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../applicationContext.xml");
settingsService =  (ISettingsService)context.getBean("SettingsService");
```

so i get the service successfully which has all crud operations i needed.
btw in applicationContext.xml i have this line

```
<bean id="SettingsService" class="my.path.to.services.SettingsService">
    <property name="settingsDAO" ref="SettingsDAO" />
</bean>
```